# Increase in the number of connections gives 504 gateway timeout error in Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-504, nginx-upstreams

I have a mail server running nginx. Whenever the number of connections increase, nginx fails and give Upstream connection error in the error.log. On the browser, it gives 504 Timeout error. How can I resolve this?

I have checked the resources that are being used by my server. They are in the optimal state. Still, I am facing this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal state"?  Is the server overloaded?

Comment: No. By optimal state, I mean that the resources of the server are minimally consumed. For instance, my RAM gets consumed by only 15%. Also, the server has more than required number of CPU resources.

Comment: What about I/O?

Comment: That too is in a good state. The maximum IO percentage that I saw a thread occupying was 18.7%

Comment: So maybe you just need to increase the gateway timeout in nginx.

Comment: But you haven't said anything about what mail service you are running, or how it is configured.  Or ... for that matter ... how nginx itself is configured.

Comment: Note that this is not a programming question, so you are unlikely to get good answers here.  StackOverflow is a programming Q&A site.